# Facebook Share Dialog - Can't share Facebook photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to share a Facebook photo using the Share Dialog JS SDK.

```
FB.ui({
  method: "share",
  href: "https://www.facebook.com/st.forte/photos/a.891684867528346.1073741825.891680260862140/891684894195010/",
}, function(response) {} );
```

**Note**: the `href` is the link to individual photo's page. Taken from Graph API.

It only open a popup with endless loading GIF like shown in picture below:

[image]

In console, it says:

```
GET https://.... 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several old question that mention about Facebook not allowing this.

I'm not sure about current state. But the easiest alternative now is to use Share button from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Then you can fill the data dynamically:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo your link here ?>></div>
```

You can't change the image button though.

Comment: Not allowing what? Sharing images?

Comment: If I remember correctly, FB doesn't allow us to manually open dialog box to share something. They require you to use that new method I linked above

Comment: I've found out that Share Dialog doesn't allow posting images, but the Feed Dialog does.